# maven release:prepare with NoClassDefFoundError while using git

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

With maven 3.6.1 and maven-release-plugin 2.5.3 when doing a `mvn release:prepare` I got an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/scm/command/untag/UntagScmResult

Here is my pom.xml relevant part:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
    <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
    <tagNameFormat>V@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And here the full exception:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.GitExeScmProvider
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/scm/command/untag/UntagScmResult
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3167)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2310)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredMethods (InjectionPoint.java:766)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:683)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision (BeanScheduler.java:230)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.getProviderByType (AbstractScmManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.makeScmRepository (AbstractScmManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.getConfiguredRepository (DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.getConfiguredRepository (DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.CheckPomPhase.execute (CheckPomPhase.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease (PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute (PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.scm.command.untag.UntagScmResult
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3167)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2310)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredMethods (InjectionPoint.java:766)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:683)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision (BeanScheduler.java:230)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.getProviderByType (AbstractScmManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.manager.AbstractScmManager.makeScmRepository (AbstractScmManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.getConfiguredRepository (DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.getConfiguredRepository (DefaultScmRepositoryConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.CheckPomPhase.execute (CheckPomPhase.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare (DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease (PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute (PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

So my question is how to fix that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The exception could be fixed by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

So the complete maven-release-plugin looks:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
    <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
    <tagNameFormat>V@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this solution also works when using jgit instead of gitexe